# Regex in android-digits

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

today I have a doubt about regex and `android:digits` property

Is there a way to set a regex in my layout?

something like

```
android:digits="^[A-Z0-9]+$"
```

> This should allow only UPPERCASE LETTERS and NUMBERS but is not working like
> that

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That property is to specify allowed characters. Surprisingly, it even allows alphabets, symbols, etc...

```xml
<EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123abc"
    android:ems="10"/>
```

This will limit the input to just 0, 1, 2, 3, a, b and c.

> Is there a way to set a regex in my layout?

You're probably could but it is limited to `EditText`s by using a custom attribute and  implementing `InputFilter`. It is not just adding extra works but making everything far more complicated and I'm pretty sure this is not something that you want to hear.

> This should allow only UPPERCASE LETTERS and NUMBERS

```xml
android:digits="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```